# Possible to use an Array for value in IF formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have spreadsheet that is made up of 3 worksheets. First one is called Main, second is one is called On and third one is called Off. In the Main sheet, when I put On or Off in the first column, I need the formula to copy the contents of 3 cells in that specific row to either the on or off sheet. I have been able to do this in google docs, using the following formula in in the On sheet.

`=IF(Main!A1="On",{Main!B1:D1},)`

Problem is it doesn't work in Excel. Best I'm able to do in Excel is only get the contents of the first cell, B1 in this case to print on the On sheet. Does anyone know of an equivalent way to write this in excel? I have tried some variations, but keep getting the response that the array con't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(Main!A1="On";A1 = B1 & A2 = C1 & A3=D1;"")
```

A1, A2, A3 being the cells you want your values copied to in the "on" or "off"-sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, hope it help someone else. `{=IF(Main!A1="On",Main!B1:D1,)}`